# command doesn't work when run from script file

Tags: linux, shell, command, debian, raspbian

I need to open my chromium browser when my raspberry pi boots up (using raspbian stretch).

I go through the following routine to start it up via command line :

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0.0

$ chromium-browser
```

This works.

---

I need to run this automatically when my raspberry pi boots up. So I create a **startup.sh** file in **/etc/init.d**

I have all the necessary permissions set up. My startup.sh file looks like :

```
export DISPLAY=:0.0
chromium-browser
```

When I run this file using ***sh startup.sh***, nothings happens and the chromium browser doesn't open. How should I make this work?

Comment: BTW, `DISPLAY=:0.0 chromium-browser` on all one line will have the same effect as the `export` followed by the execution on two different lines, except insofar as the `export` will leave the variable in the environment of the shell even after the process is started.

Comment: that said, "doesn't work" isn't an adequate description for anyone to provide a useful answer. Please provide the **exact** error message.

Comment: There is no error message. The chromium browser simply doesn't open.

Comment: Process returns immediately? Process hangs? What's the exit status? Are there any entries left behind in the process table? Make an *effort* here.

Comment: ...frankly, it's somewhat unusual and surprising to not have *any* logs. If this is a release build, I'd consider `chromium-browser --enable-logging --log-level 0`.

Comment: I'd also suggest starting with a simpler X11 client -- `xclock` or `xterm` or such; determining whether that works will help isolate whether this is a Chromium-specific or more general issue.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I made it work using 
@reboot DISPLAY=:0.0 chromium-browser in my crontab file.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does `sh -x startup.sh` emit on stderr?